# pass dropdownlist value to submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, html-select

I am currently working with MVC4 and Mysql database. I have Model called MessageExchangeModel and MY controller called FirstController and My action are DisplayUsersDetails. I am currently using DropDownList to display the username from database. THE PROBLEM is: when I select any username then click on Find button then nothing happen !! I believe that the value of the selected item from drop down list does not passed !

Comment: You forgot to enter image description here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by checking the database connection ! I have put different connection that why does not display anything

cheers